# How to save a pandas DataFrame with custom types using pyarrow and parquet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parquet, pyarrow

I want to save a pandas DataFrame to parquet, but I have some unsupported types in it (for example bson ObjectIds).

Throughout the examples we use:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
```

Here's a minimal example to show the situation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {'name': 'alice', 'oid': ObjectId('5e9992543bfddb58073803e7')},
        {'name': 'bob',   'oid': ObjectId('5e9992543bfddb58073803e8')},
    ]
)

df.to_parquet('some_path')
```

And we get:

```
ArrowInvalid: ('Could not convert 5e9992543bfddb58073803e7 with type ObjectId: did not recognize Python value type when inferring an Arrow data type', 'Conversion failed for column oid with type object')
```

I tried to follow this reference: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/extending_types.html

Thus I wrote the following type extension:

```
class ObjectIdType(pa.ExtensionType):

    def __init__(self):
        pa.ExtensionType.__init__(self, pa.binary(12), "my_package.objectid")

    def __arrow_ext_serialize__(self):
        # since we don't have a parametrized type, we don't need extra
        # metadata to be deserialized
        return b''

    @classmethod
    def __arrow_ext_deserialize__(self, storage_type, serialized):
        # return an instance of this subclass given the serialized
        # metadata.
        return ObjectId()
```

And was able to get a working pyarray for my `oid` column:

```
values = df['oid']
storage_array = pa.array(values.map(lambda oid: oid.binary), type=pa.binary(12))
pa.ExtensionArray.from_storage(objectid_type, storage_array)
```

Now where I’m stuck, and cannot find any good solution on the internet, is how to save my df to parquet, letting it interpret which column needs which `Extension`. I might change columns in the future, and I have several different types that need this treatment.

**How can I simply create parquet file from dataframes and restore them while transparently converting the types ?**

I tried to create a `pyarrow.Table` object, and append columns to it after preprocessing, but it doesn’t work as `table.append_column` takes binary columns and not `pyarrow.Arrays`, plus the whole `isinstance` thing looks like a terrible solution.

```
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame())
for col, values in test_df.iteritems():

    if isinstance(values.iloc[0], ObjectId):
        arr = pa.array(
            values.map(lambda oid: oid.binary), type=pa.binary(12)
        )

    elif isinstance(values.iloc[0], ...):
        ...

    else:
        arr = pa.array(values)

    table.append_column(arr, col)  # FAILS (wrong type)
```

**Pseudocode of the ideal solution:**

```
parquetize(df, path, my_custom_types_conversions)
# ...
new_df = unparquetize(path, my_custom_types_conversions)

assert df.equals(new_df)  # types have been correctly restored
```

I’m getting lost in pyarrow’s doc on if I should use `ExtensionType`, `serialization` or other things to write these functions. Any pointer would be appreciated.

Side note, I do not need `parquet` at all means, the main issue is to being able to save and restore dataframes with custom types `quickly` and `space efficiently`. I tried a solution based on jsonifying and gziping the dataframe, but it was too slow.

Comment: I can contribute that at the least your extension class is missing a requisite function for conversion from pandas, `to_pandas_dtype`, see this section in detail https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/extending_types.html#conversion-to-pandas. I still didn't manage to get to a working solution though (I was attempting for UUIDs).

Comment: Why not pickle the dataframe and store it? You can unpickle it to get the exact copy.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is probably because the 'ObjectId' is not a defined keyword in python hence it is throwing up this exception in type conversion.

I tried the example you provided and tried by casting the  oid values as string type during dataframe creation and it worked.

Check below the steps:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {'name': 'alice', 'oid': "ObjectId('5e9992543bfddb58073803e7')"},
        {'name': 'bob',   'oid': "ObjectId('5e9992543bfddb58073803e8')"},
    ]
)

df.to_parquet('parquet_file.parquet')
```

```
df1 = pd.read_parquet('parquet_file.parquet',engine='pyarrow')
df1
```

output:

```
    name    oid
0   alice   ObjectId('5e9992543bfddb58073803e7')
1   bob ObjectId('5e9992543bfddb58073803e8')
```

Answer (score -2):

You could write a method that reads the column names and types and outputs a new DF with the columns converted to compatible types, using a switch-case pattern to choose what type to convert column to (or whether to leave it as is).